# Ansible can't pass varibles to roles using lookup?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to pass some rsa public keys to ansible roles from ansible playbook, however, I find that ansible can't pass varibles when using lookup.

```
---
- hosts: gateway
  vars: 
    keys:
      - "{{ lookup('file', './files/rsa_pubs/sake1.pub') }}"
      - "{{ lookup('file', './files/rsa_pubs/sake2.pub') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Set gateway rsa public file.
      import_role: 
        name: ssh_rsa_setting
      vars:
        # rsa_pub_keys:
        #   - "{{ lookup('file', './files/rsa_pubs/sake1.pub') }}"
        #   - "{{ lookup('file', './files/rsa_pubs/sake2.pub') }}"
        rsa_pub_keys: keys
```

The commneted code failed while using varible "keys" to pass the rsa keys seems fine.
I've tried to use "include_role" instead "import_role", nothing changes.
I want to know why and how to properly pass the list varibles to roles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rsa_pub_keys: keys` => `rsa_pub_keys: "{{ keys }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you. It help me understand "{{}}". Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is kikd of the base of using jinja2 inside ansible you should get familiar with before going any further: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2

Answer (score -1):

As @Zeitounator  suggest, "{{}}" should be used!